# Jmeter load testing for login

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load-testing

I want to test how many users can concurrently login to the application. For that, can I create one user name and password and increase the thread to 100? or should I create 100 username and passwords and load it somehow?

Comment: *how many users can concurrently* usually means different users

Comment: @user7294900 Yes. I want to know which path should I follow

Comment: Does you server allow to login with same user on same machine multiple times and keep all those sessions open concurrently? most probably not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat each JMeter thread (virtual user) as the real user using a real browser, it means:

1. Different credentials (can be provided via [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config))
2. Properly simulating browser network footprint including (but not limited to)

   - Sending and receiving [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) (and [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) as special header sub-type)
   - Downloading [embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) (images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds)
   - Representing [browser cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)
   - Simulating [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests
3. Mimicking real user "think time" as real users don't hammer application non-stop, they need some time to "think" between operations so consider adding appropriate [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers)
4. Login itself won't tell you full story, you need to produce realistic workload, i.e. after logging in user should start doing something which he's normally doing

Answer (score 0):

Usually concurrent users = different users, because it should be based on [real case scenario](https://testguild.com/performance-testing-concepts-what-are-concurrent-users/)

> During a load test you try to emulate real-world conditions

If you want to have concurrent users in your application you should use different users because most servers won't allow same user to use your application with multiple sessions, also your application wants to (test) support multiple users so you need to load test the common scenario first.

If your application allows user to use your application with multiple sessions
, then add a second load test which test it also